Back Button alternate way
Is there any other better alternate way to write the code with the same output?
const handleGoBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (previousStep === 0) {
        openToast('warning', 'You are going back to dashboard');
        navigate('/dashboard');
    }
    else {
        dispatch(setCurrentStep(previousStep));
        navigate(stepRoutes[previousStep.toString()]);
    }
}, [dispatch, navigate, previousStep]);

return (
    <div className={styles.backButton} onClick={handleGoBack}>
      <IoArrowBackOutline className={styles.backIcon} />
      <Localize>Back</Localize>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BackButton;

const stepRoutes: Record<string, string> = {
  1: '/appointments/choose-specialty',
  2: '/appointments/select-doctor',
  3: '/appointments/time-slot',
  4: '/appointmenst/add-details',
  5: '/appointments/payment',
};


"Is there any other better alternate way to write the code" - With regards to what? What specifically needs improvement? "with the same output?" - Same output as what? Is there some issue or problem with the code you have currently? Please [edit] to clarify what specifically you want help with.

const stepRoutes: Record<number, string> = {
  1: '/appointments/choose-specialty',
  2: '/appointments/select-doctor',
  3: '/appointments/time-slot',
  4: '/appointments/add-details',
  5: '/appointments/payment',
};

const BackButton: React.FC<{ previousStep: number }> = ({ previousStep }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleGoBack = useCallback(() => {
    if (previousStep === 0) {
      openToast('warning', 'You are going back to the dashboard');
      navigate('/dashboard');
    } else {
      const route = stepRoutes[previousStep];
      if (route) {
        dispatch(setCurrentStep(previousStep));
        navigate(route);
      } else {
        console.error(`No route found for step ${previousStep}`);
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, navigate, previousStep]);

  return (
    <div className={styles.backButton} onClick={handleGoBack}>
      <IoArrowBackOutline className={styles.backIcon} />
      <span>Back</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BackButton;

I Hope this is help for you.
